# TermDocumentMatrix Error rare characters (spanish)

Tags: text, data-mining

I already tried a lot of things, maybe I´m blind but, I continue getting rare coded characters. What can I do? Where is the mistake in the code? or in the setting?

Fist this is my session information :

```
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Mexico.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Mexico.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Mexico.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
    [5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Mexico.1252



#########
my_data <- read_excel("discursosData.xlsx")
text <- my_data$`Discurso Apertura`[1]
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("spanish"))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
termDocMat <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
m <- as.matrix(termDocMat)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
head(d,10)
```

#

And I get :

```
word freq
vamos       vamos   18
xico         xico   17
quiero     quiero   10
campaÃ     campaÃ    9
venes       venes    9
gobierno gobierno    8
manera     manera    8
amigo       amigo    7
horas       horas    7
soÃ           soÃ    7
```

For example "campaÃ " should be "campaña", "xico" it should be "méxico". it´s seems  when the system find accents or "ñ" change it for a rare charcater.

What is wrong? please help me. Thank you

Comment: This looks like an encoding problem.

Comment: Type `help(Encoding)` in the R console.

Comment: Tks for your answer. I know but I don´t know how to fix it.

Comment: Try saving the data in "UTF-8" encoding and read it in with the same, and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried saving the data as you recommend me, with UTF-8 Encoding and I still have the same problem. I tried also incov and Encoding, but it doesn´t work.

Comment: Sometimes the output prints differently in the R console compared to inside an R markdown (Rmd) file. Are you printing to the R console?

Comment: You can also try `guess_encoding()` function in the readr package to determine the encoding of your Excel file and at different stages of your code.

Comment: I´m using RStudio, I will try guess_encoding() then. Tks.

Comment: Try it on a Linux system, as this looks much like utf-8 encoding to me, which is easy to use on Linux and OSX. Make sure to check for encoding parameters in read_excel, and consider converting the encoding of `text` if necessary prior to converting it into a corpus.